# using two swc files (movie clip inside have the same instance name);

Tags: flash, swc

I have two SWC files first.swc and second.swc
the problem : movieclips inside this two SWC files have the same instance names ( the difference is the graphics applied for them).

**How can i call a movieclip from the first or the second SWC files if they have the same instance name.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way. Think that every symbol from all your swc files are stored at one swc file. But there is complex solution: use tool like Maven to build your project. Anyway I think that you are doing something wrong.